# ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: "N/A" ... nice but which column?

Tags: postgresql, error-handling, postgresql-9.5

I am running a function in PostgreSQL which contains several functions which purpose is to load data from foreign tables into mine. While running I get this error:

> [SELECT - 0 row(s), 762.353 secs]  [Error Code: 0, SQL State: 22P02]  ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: "N/A"
>     Where: PL/pgSQL function import_data_3(integer,timestamp with time zone,timestamp with time zone,integer) line 16 at SQL statement
>   SQL statement "SELECT import_data_3(import, beg, end_t, is_l)"
>   PL/pgSQL function data_import_all(timestamp with time zone,timestamp with time zone,integer,integer) line 31 at PERFORM

I know what that means and also its reason I am trying to convert 'N/A' string to number and there for this error, problem is this lousy error does not specify the column where the error occurred.

Is there a way to get more precise error message which would tell me the exact column where the error happened?

Comment: show us the query you are using, and some sample data to have idea what are you doing. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

It's not in the column but in one of the parameters that are passed to `import_data_3`.

You called the query `SELECT import_data_3(import, beg, end_t, is_l)`.

The specification of this function is `import_data_3(integer,timestamp with time zone,timestamp with time zone,integer)`

Since you got the error

> invalid input syntax for type numeric: "N/A"

this most likely means that either first parameter "import" or the last one "is_l" contain the value "N/A". Try to debug the calling code of the function `data_import_all` and see how those two parameter values are generated.

Comment: No that is not the case, all parametrs are correct ......... I actually manage to run the program but I had to blindly put "case when columnXY = 'N/A' then null else columnXY end" on each column the function is operate due to error message was not specifing which one caused the error